Nextjs14 Trpc app Error: headers was called outside a request scope
System:
    OS: Linux 4.19 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
    CPU: (16) x64 AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
    Memory: 5.58 GB / 7.73 GB
    Container: Yes
    Shell: 5.9 - /usr/bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.13.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.13.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.5.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.13.1/bin/npm
    pnpm: 9.1.0 - ~/.local/share/pnpm/pnpm
    bun: 1.1.27 - ~/.bun/bin/bun
  npmPackages:
    typescript: ^5.4.5 => 5.6.3

"lucia": "^3.2.0",
"next": "14.2.3",
"@tanstack/react-query": "^5.39.0",
"@trpc/client": "next",
"@trpc/react-query": "next",
"@trpc/server": "next",

Using a nextjs14 app router webapp with a trpc server and trpc client
dashboard/page.tsx is a server component which further renders other client components such as ContentCarousel
//ContentCarousel.tsx
`use client`  
import { api } from '@/lib/trpc/react';
const ContentCarousel = ({
  options
}: CarouselProps) => {
const queryResult = api.home.queryMedia.useQuery(options);

This issue happens in production mode or when trying to run next build.
it returns
Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).
Digest: 3247530286

Error: `headers` was called outside a request scope. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-dynamic-api-wrong-context
    at getExpectedRequestStore (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/request-async-storage.external.js:28:11)
    at d (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/4902.js:139:21531)
    at /home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/4868.js:1:4786
    at /home/ridhwaans/Source/test/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:185072
    at /home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/8419.js:4:1730
    at Object.apply (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/chunks/8419.js:4:715)
    at ee (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:16:1399)
    at 67268 (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:16:4573)
    at t (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 47197 (/home/ridhwaans/Source/test/apps/web/.next/server/app/dashboard/page.js:1:1721) {
  digest: '212130697'
}

The only reference to headers I found are in the trpcContext, trpc client and trpc dynamic route /trpc/[trpc]/route.ts .
Not sure if and which client component is calling server component, or, if the issue is trpc, lucia auth, or something else. There is so much code
Need someone to help debug because I spend a day trying to find the cause of Error: headers was called outside a request scope https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-dynamic-api-wrong-context and I could not find it
To reproduce

Use the code for trpcContext
Run next build. Run next start in production mode
Load the page and read the console log
I havent shared the server components & client components that use trpc. All app router pages share a layout.tsx  and that layout has the trpcprovider wrapper

//api/src/trpc.ts
import { initTRPC, TRPCError } from '@trpc/server';
import superjson from 'superjson';
import { ZodError } from 'zod';

import { auth } from '@project/auth';
import { db } from '@project/db';

export const createTRPCContext = async (opts: { headers: Headers }) => {
  const { session, user } = await auth();

  return {
    db,
    session,
    user,
    ...opts,
  };
};

const t = initTRPC.context<typeof createTRPCContext>().create({
  transformer: superjson,
  errorFormatter({ shape, error }) {
    return {
      ...shape,
      data: {
        ...shape.data,
        zodError:
          error.cause instanceof ZodError ? error.cause.flatten() : null,
      },
    };
  },
});
export const createCallerFactory = t.createCallerFactory;

export const createRouter = t.router;

export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;

export const protectedProcedure = t.procedure.use(({ ctx, next }) => {
  if (!ctx.session || !ctx.user) {
    throw new TRPCError({ code: 'UNAUTHORIZED' });
  }

  return next({
    ctx: {
      session: { ...ctx.session },
      user: { ...ctx.user },
    },
  });
});


//app/web/src/lib/trpc/react.tsx
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { loggerLink, unstable_httpBatchStreamLink } from '@trpc/client';
import { createTRPCReact } from '@trpc/react-query';
import { type inferRouterInputs, type inferRouterOutputs } from '@trpc/server';
import superjson from 'superjson';

import { type AppRouter } from '@project/api';
import { getBaseUrl } from '@project/utils/url';

const createQueryClient = () => new QueryClient();

let clientQueryClientSingleton: QueryClient | undefined = undefined;
const getQueryClient = () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return createQueryClient();
  }
  return (clientQueryClientSingleton ??= createQueryClient());
};

export const api = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();

export type RouterInputs = inferRouterInputs<AppRouter>;
export type RouterOutputs = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>;

/**
 * This component is used to initialize the trpc & react-query pairing on the client side.
 * @param props The props to the component.
 * @param props.children The children to render.
 * @returns react-query and trpc providers wrapper around the children.
 */
export function TRPCReactProvider(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();

  const [trpcClient] = useState(() =>
    api.createClient({
      links: [
        loggerLink({
          enabled: (op) =>
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ||
            (op.direction === 'down' && op.result instanceof Error),
        }),
        unstable_httpBatchStreamLink({
          transformer: superjson,
          url: getBaseUrl() + '/api/trpc',
          headers: () => {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.set('x-trpc-source', 'nextjs-react');
            return headers;
          },
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <api.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
        {props.children}
      </api.Provider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}


//app/web/src/lib/trpc/server.ts
import 'server-only';

import { cache } from 'react';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

import { createCaller, createTRPCContext } from '@project/api';

const createContext = cache(async () => {
  const heads = new Headers(headers());
  heads.set('x-trpc-source', 'rsc');

  return createTRPCContext({
    headers: heads,
  });
});

export const api = createCaller(createContext);


//app/web/src/app/api/trpc/[trpc]/route.ts
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { fetchRequestHandler } from '@trpc/server/adapters/fetch';

import { appRouter, createTRPCContext } from '@project/api';
import { env } from '@project/env/web';

const createContext = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  return createTRPCContext({
    headers: req.headers,
  });
};

const handler = (req: NextRequest) =>
  fetchRequestHandler({
    endpoint: '/api/trpc',
    req,
    router: appRouter,
    createContext: () => createContext(req),
    onError: ({ path, error }) => {
      if (env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        console.error(
          `❌ tRPC failed on ${path ?? '<no-path>'}: ${error.message}`,
        );
      }
    },
  });

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


No response
‍‍ Contributing

[ ] ‍♂️ Yes, I'd be down to file a PR fixing this bug!

Funding

You can sponsor this specific effort via a Polar.sh pledge below
We receive the pledge once the issue is completed & verified



